# Открытие новой вкладки на соседнем мониторе на Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Добрейшего!
Работаю на 2х мониторах. В обоих открыт chrome (двумя окнами, с отличными друг от друга наборами вкладок).
На левом мониторе, в одной из вкладок есть кнопка, при нажатии которой, перехожу в карточку клиента.
Для себя удобнее чтобы открывалась в новой вкладке.
Сайт не мой, поэтому через расширение chrome (user js and css) добавил

```
onclick="window.open('https://www.amocrm.ru/', '_blank'")
```

Получилось так:

```
<button type="button" id="open_customer_card" onclick="window.open('https://www.amocrm.ru/', '_blank'");></button>
```

Вкладка разумеется открывается соседней вкладкой на левом мониторе.

**Как сделать открытие этой вкладки на правом мониторе без перетаскивания вкладки с левого монитора, на правый монитор?**

Answer (score 1):

Одной строкой кода не обойтись.

Окон браузера может быть и не два, по хорошему необходимо идентифицировать целевое окно для открытия определенных типов вкладок.

Примерный порядок операций:

1. Реализация управления (либо одно/либо другое):

   - создание Popup-окна с кнопками управления - масса возможностей
   - click по значку расширения - [onClicked](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/action/#event-onClicked)
2. Получение и установка целевого окна:

   - получение [windows.getCurrent()](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/windows/#method-getCurrent)
   - если это Popup - отправляем `Window.id` в фоновый скрипт расширения [runtime.sendMessage()](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#method-sendMessage)
   - на этом этапе фиксируется целевой `Window.id`, в том числе можно указать для чего этот `id`
3. Скрипт контента по клику отправляет в фон необходимый `url` страницы `runtime.sendMessage()` и, тем самым, заявляет о желании открыть Tab
4. Фон создает новую вкладку с заранее известным `Window.id` и `url` полученным от Tab-а [tabs.create({windowId,...}, ...)](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#method-create)

- При желании можно сразу и активировать этот Tab. При еще большем желании - управлять открытием/активацией/переходом(и даже установкой курсора в input-ы) разных типов вкладок в разных окнах.
- При отсутствии желания можно получить все имеющиеся окна, собственное окно Tab-а и открыть вкладку в `Window.id !== SelfWindow.id`, если их всего 2. Правда кода особо меньше не станет.